# What is the species name of this plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Rubbing the leaves between your fingers feel strong, pleasant aroma of citrus.

The leaves are not fuzzy and are about 2 cm long.

[image]

In Germany.

Comment: Please provide your location too.

Comment: Are the leaves fuzzy? I can't tell...  Also please add dimensions of leaves and any pictures of flowers if present.  A comment about where you got the plant could help, too.

Comment: The leaves are not fuzzy, about 2 centimeters in length. In Germany.

Comment: Where exactly did you find it? Assuming you found it growing in the wild. Please be as specific as possible, location/habitat.

Comment: One acquaintance gave. It is grown in pots in the room. He said that can eat.

Comment: He said that can eat. -what do you mean?

Comment: Can use as spice.